Game slowing motion down instead of low FPS
I'm making a bird game where you fly around a somewhat large environment of low poly assets. During testing, I found some behavior on one device that I cannot explain:
The game slows down instead of reducing frame rate when looking into the map's center with the most objects visible. The animations, physics and sounds all slow down. Every few seconds, it seems to catch up, before instantly slowing down again. It runs completely normal when you look in directions where the max frame rate is reached.

This behavior only happens on medium or higher quality (mostly default settings), so it's maybe tied to vsync
It stops immediately when recording or screen sharing, or receiving a discord screen share
It is most likely not a deltaTime issue, since everything works frame independent with consistent speeds on other devices

The project is made with:

URP
Lightmapping
Rigidbody player controller
A map based on low-poly assets by synty, including particles, mesh colliders.
Rigidbody interpolation (not required for reproduction)
Cinemachine (not required for reproduction)
Crossfade LODs (not required for reproduction)


During profiling, I found no hint on what is going on, but I'm not entirely comfortable using the profiler. You can find two profiling sessions below. If you need any more information from the profiler, let me know.
Do you know this behavior and possible causes, or can you help me debug this issue? Thanks for your time!

Update
During further testing we found out:

Turning off Adaptive Sync on the monitor disabled the bug, but turning it on again did not completely restore the bug. Now, the bug appears on Medium quality, but not on Ultra, which had the bug until now.
I added a speedometer that shows the rigidbody's velocity.magnitude on screen. It doesn't change during any slow-downs.


Code
Below is my movement code, in case it helps. This is reduced a lot from the original state, but still triggers the bug.
void Update() {
    FetchInput(); // Reads values from new Input System and calculated intended directions for ground and air control.
    Sounds(); // Play some wooshes and wind noise. Flapping sounds are triggered by animation events though.
    Animate(); // Rotate bird body.
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    Movement(); // Rotate player rigidbody, add thrust and redirect velocity
}

void Movement() {
    UpdateGroundCheck();
    UpdateSlopeSliding();

    _steerXSmooth = _inputState.steer.x; // These had easing before, removed for debugging
    _steerYSmooth = _inputState.steer.y;
    _animator.SetFloat("Turn", _steerXSmooth);

    _currentGlidePitch =  Utils.ShiftedRemap(
        -_inputState.thrust,
        -1f, -.5f, 0f,
        -_defaultRisingPitch, 0f, -_defaultGlidingPitch
    );
    // ShiftedRemap is like a linear remap, but shifts a middle point.
    _currentPitch = Utils.ShiftedRemap(
        _inputState.steer.y,
        -1, 0, 1,
        -45, _currentGlidePitch, 65
    );
    // _currentPitch is used for ascending and descending. the rigidbody is not rotated according to the pitch, only the visual mesh.

    // Adjust Max Speed
    _targetMaxSpeed = maxSpeed + _inputState.steer.y * (maxSpeed * .3f);
    if (_targetMaxSpeed > maxSpeed) {
        // Increase downwards max speed
        _targetMaxSpeed *= 1.25f;
    }
    _currentMaxSpeed = _targetMaxSpeed;

    if (IsStanding()) {
        if (!_wasStandingLastFixedUpdate) {
            if (!_wasFallingLastFrame) {
                _timeSinceLanded = 0;
            }
            _landingDirection = (_rb.velocity + Vector3.down * _rb.velocity.y).normalized;
            _cooldownManager.Begin("TakeOff"); // Prevent instant takeoff
            ResetAnimatorTrigger("TakeOff");
            SetAnimatorTrigger("TouchDown");
            if (_rawDistanceToGround < 0) {
                _rb.MovePosition(_rb.position + Vector3.up * -_rawDistanceToGround);
            }
        }

        _animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0f);
        _animator.SetFloat("Brake", 0f);

        _rb.drag = 4f;

        // Walk relative to Camera
        float walkSpeed = Mathf.Clamp01(_inputState.steer.magnitude);
        _animator.SetFloat("Walk", walkSpeed);

        Vector3 moveDirection = GetCamRelativeInputDirection(_inputState.steer).normalized;
        _rb.velocity = walkSpeed * groundMoveSpeed * moveDirection;

        // Turn in walk direction
        if (_inputState.steer.magnitude > 0) {
            _rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.RotateTowards(_rb.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection), 360f * Time.fixedDeltaTime * _inputState.steer.magnitude));
        }

        // Add velocity based on slope
        _rb.velocity = AdjustVelocityToSlope(_rb.velocity);

        // Take off if conditions are met
        MaybeTakeOff();

        _lastStandingPosition = m_trans.position;
        _wasFallingLastFrame = false;
    }
    else if (IsFalling()) { // IsFalling is true, when the player goes off a ledge and hasn't fallen far
        // Don't flap while falling a little
        ResetAnimatorTrigger("TouchDown");
        _animator.SetFloat("Walk", 0f);

        TurnOnGround();
        MaybeTakeOff();

        _wasFallingLastFrame = true;
    }
    else { // Flying
        if (_wasStandingLastFixedUpdate || _wasFallingLastFrame) {
            ResetAnimatorTrigger("TouchDown");
            SetAnimatorTrigger("TakeOff");
            _timeSinceTakeOff = 0f;
            brakeAmount = 0f;
        }

        _animator.SetFloat("Walk", 0f);

        _rb.drag = .01f;

        // Yaw
        _yawDelta = horizontalStrength * (1 + _inputState.brake) * _steerXSmooth;
        _rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.AngleAxis(_yawDelta * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 50f, Vector3.up) * _rb.rotation);

        _rb.velocity = Quaternion.AngleAxis(_yawDelta * Time.fixedDeltaTime * 50f, Vector3.up) * _rb.velocity;

        // Thrust
        _rb.AddForce(flapStrength * _inputState.thrust * (GetForwardsDirection() + GetUpwardsDirection() / 2).normalized, ForceMode.Force);
        _animator.SetFloat("Speed", _inputState.thrust);

        // Limit velocity
        _rb.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(_rb.velocity, _currentMaxSpeed);

        _lastStandingPosition = Vector3.up * Mathf.Infinity;
        _wasFallingLastFrame = false;
    }

    // Track State
    if (_rb.velocity.magnitude < 0.0001f) {
        _rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        _rbSleptFor += Time.deltaTime;
        _rbSleptForFixedUpdates += 1;
    }
    else {
        _rbSleptFor = 0f;
        _rbSleptForFixedUpdates = 0;
    }

    _wasStandingLastFixedUpdate = IsStanding();
}


Profiling

Turning around from looking at a complex part of the map to a simple part. The spikes seem to line up with the catch-up phases. One of the biggest contributors to the differing frame times is Gfx.WaitForPresentOnGfxThread (half of the green section).



Looking at a complex part — first with screen sharing on, then with screen sharing off. I don't see a difference in the profiler.





Can you show how your player controller code manipulates the Rigidbody? It's possible it's set up in a way that's not framerate independent.

Yes, I will extract all parts of the code relevant to the movement and rigidbody.

I added the code and some further testing results in the question.

Nothing jumps out to my eye as an obvious problem. The profiler seems to show you're running at a consistent 60+ fps, so there's no evidence of a slowdown that would hit the max delta time and start skipping physics steps, slowing the simulation. I'm stumped.

What version of Unity are you using? Have you tried updating the GPU drivers on the device (if possible)?

I used Unity 2022.3.7 and 2022.3.31. The tester was on an outdated Nvidia driver, after updating we cannot reproduce the problem anymore.
